# sequelize dynamic db config

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I want to ask if it's possible to use promise based config in sequelize-cli.
So, the idea behind it is that my config file is in AWS S3, but it's not formatted to match sequelize's config file (I have to reformat it in the code)

I didn't find anything in the documentation. http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/migrations.html#dynamic-configuration. They say they can use a js file, but can the js file download the config file first from S3?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR you can export a promise in `config.js` which return the configuration object. e.g.:

```
module.exports = somePromise().then(data => {
  ....,
  production: {
    username: data.user,
    password: data.password,
    database: data.db,
    host: data.host,
    dialect: 'mysql',
  },
})
```

After an extensive research, I found out that `config.js` can actually handle promise.

So to make it work, you need to provide `.sequelizerc` file in the root folder (where you use sequelize) and copy this to the file

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  'config': path.resolve('config', 'config.js')
}
```

then, create a `config.js` file. These steps is documented in http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/migrations.html#dynamic-configuration

The next step is to use promise in `config.js`. I found an answer on sequelize github issues tracker and found this issue: https://github.com/sequelize/cli/issues/668